# How do i can convert Factor value to integer in a data set (ex: Housing.dataset)

Tags: r

the below is the factor data (i.e.,Column name : Property count)
i am try to convert this to numeric / integer, how to convert the entire column data to numeric / integer

**Factor w/ 343 levels "NA","1008","10160",..: 191 191 191 191 191 191 191 191 191 191 ...**

Comment: is anybody there to help on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use as.numeric(column with vector of values)